# How to use browser extensions on my browser with Selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Tampermonkey on Chrome with selenium webdriver. But when Selenium webdriver opens chrome. All extensions aren't present. Is there any way to enable them? I am using python

Try to automate with Tampermonkey on chrome but the extensions don't appear

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to add an extension, first you need to get the crx file of the extension, you can download it form websites like [CrxDownloader](https://crx-downloader.com/)  after that save it locally and update extension path in below code
I have Tested it locally and able to add it

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('pathtoExtension/Tampermonkey.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

[image]